# parallel.foreach and httpclient - strange behaviour

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, asp.net-web-api2

I have a piece of code that loops over a collection and calls httpclient for each iteration. The api that the httpclient calls, takes on average 30-40ms to execute. Calling it sequentially, I get the expected outcome, however as soon as I use Parallel.foreach, it takes longer. Looking closely in the logs, I can see quite a few httpclient calls take more 1000ms to execute and then the time drops back to 30-40ms. Looking in the api logs, I can see it barely goes over 100ms. I am not sure why I get this spike.

The code is

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
  var content = new StringContent(parameters, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
  var response = client.PostAsync(url, content);
  _log.Info(string.Format("Took {0} ms to send post", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
  watch.Restart();

  var responseString = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  _log.Info(string.Format("Took {0} ms to readstring after post", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
}
```

The parallel call is something like this

```
    Console.WriteLine("starting parallel...");
    Parallel.ForEach(recipientCollections, recipientCollection => 
      {    
        // A lot of processing happens here to create relevant content
        var secondaryCountryRecipientList = string.Join(",",refinedCountryRecipients);
        var emailApiParams = new SendEmailParametersModel(CountrySubscriberApplicationId,
                                        queueItem.SitecoreId, queueItem.Version, queueItem.Language, countryFeedItem.Subject,
                                        countryFeedItem.Html, countryFeedItem.From, _recipientsFormatter.Format(secondaryCountryRecipientList));

       log.Info(string.Format("Sending email request for {0}. Recipients {1}",                                        queueItem.SitecoreId, secondaryCountryRecipientList));

        var response = _notificationsApi.Invoke(emailApiParams);
        });
```

thanks

Comment: Are you sending all of these requests to the same host?

Comment: why do you create `HttpClient` for each call?

Comment: Please post all the code. This is missing the Parallel statement so it's tough to see where the problem may be. I  am noticing the lack of the await keyword on PostAsync.

Comment: The server may be taking time in replying to request when coming in large numbers. Async is good but parallel requests to server should be avoided.

Comment: @SarveshMishra why should parallel requests to a server be avoided? This is fine and should be encouraged as long as the server can handle it. There are things to consider like number of parallel requests, but why avoid them? Browsers will fire 20 requests at once (5 per domain). I've done many tests from 2-1000 parallel requests and there is a sweet spot depending on the client computer and the server. Trial and error to find the sweet spot for the OP.

Comment: @spender, yes they are all going to the same host.

Comment: @Aleksey, the api call is behind a service which is a reusable component.

Comment: @ManOVision, the parallel code is now also added

Comment: @Actuary, so it can be created once in let's say constructor of this component

Comment: @AlekseyL. the service is injected only once. however each Invoke call instantiates a new httpclient object. So yes, httpclient can be made singleton object in theory

Comment: Just added MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4, and that straight away got the response time to 25% and the logs show expected api call time. Have to investigate this further

Comment: @Actuary try to reuse single instance of `HttpClient` this should improve performance on client side

Comment: @Actuary unless you change [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit(v=vs.110).aspx) .NET will allow only 2 connections per server. That's actually an HTTP recommendation.

Answer (score 6):

By default .NET allows only 2 connections per server. To change this you have to change the value of [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit(v=vs.110).aspx) to a larger value, eg 20 or 100.

This won't prevent flooding the server or consuming too much memory if you make too many requests though. A better option would be to use an [ActionBlock< T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684(v=vs.110).aspx) to buffer requests and send them in parallel in a controlled function, eg:

```
 ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit =20;

 var client = new HttpClient();

 var blockOptions=new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions{MaxDegreeOfParallelism=10};

 var emailBlock=new ActionBlock<SendEmailParametersModel>(async arameters=>
     {
         var watch=new Stopwatch();
         var content = new StringContent(parameters, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
         var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
         _log.Info(..);
         watch.Restart();

         var responseString = await response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         _log.Info(...);
 });
```

Sending the emails doesn't require parallel invocation any more:

```
foreach(var recipientCollection in recipientCollections)
{
    var secondaryCountryRecipientList = string.Join(",",refinedCountryRecipients);
    var emailApiParams = new SendEmailParametersModel(CountrySubscriberApplicationId, queueItem.SitecoreId, queueItem.Version, queueItem.Language, countryFeedItem.Subject,countryFeedItem.Html, countryFeedItem.From, _recipientsFormatter.Format(secondaryCountryRecipientList));

   emailBlock.Post(emailApiParams);
   log.Info(...);
}
emailBlock.Complete();
await emailBlock.Completion();
```

`HttpClient` is thread-safe which allows you to use the same client for all requests.

The code above will buffer all requests and execute them 10 at a time. Calling `Complete()` tells the block to complete everything and stop processing new messages. `await emailBlock.Completion()` waits for all existing messages to finish before proceeding

Comment: I'm upvoting this because `Parallel` is actually a terrible primitive for IO. IO really needs a fixed DOP and `Parallel` only has a maximum. My own solution to this is a parallel async `Select` helper method but the framework does not have one.

Comment: @usr not yet - they added an asynchronouse enumerator in CoreFxLab to support channels. Channels would be a great alternative to the lone ActionBlock.

Comment: As I understand it a channel is for single producer single consumer cases. I think we just need a parallel async select. I see people needing this on Stack Overflow all the time and then they hack a bad solution like it happened here.

Answer (score 2):

You are overloading the server. `Parallel` has no idea how many threads are optimal for your specific web service. You will get erratic results. In fact if the loop runs for a long time the thread count can rise into the hundreds and into the thousands (really!). Empirically determine the right DOP and fix the DOP.

When the service is overloaded it's not unusual to see very high servicing times. How else could it be? There's not enough capacity to do it quickly.

```
 var responseString = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
```

Here, you are missing a `.Result` call. The timing currently is off but this does not change the conclusion.

You also might be hitting the .NET concurrent request limit for HTTP calls. The default is 2.

Comment: Another possibility is that the code is hitting the 2 HTTP requests per domain limit.

Comment: Of course, how could I forget about that given that it has produces 10k questions already. Editing.