# Best way to call Vendor API for 5000 times

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a collection object with 5000 items and for every row I need to make a api call with POST method.

Here my sample data

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'ab' |
| 2 | 'ax' |
| 3 | 'sg' |
| 4 | 'sx' |
| 5 | '1b' |
| 6 | '3a' |
| 5000 | '3b' |

This is what have written so far...Code

```
foreach (var item in myList)
{
  APICall(item.id, item.value);
}

public void APICall(int Id, string value)
{
    try
    {
        var _Id = string.Format("request_Id[{0}]", Id);
        var _fieldValue = string.Format("_FieldValue[{0}]", value);
        var serviceURL = apiURL + "/" + _Id + _fieldValue;
        UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest
        {
            Instance = new Instance()
            {
                InstanceId = _Id + _fieldValue,
                ClassName = "CurrentValue",
                Properties = new Propertie()
                {
                    Value = value
                },
                ChangeState = "modified"
            }
        };

        //Serialize object to JSON
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(updateRequest);

        //Call the web api
        var client = new RestClient(serviceURL)
        {
            Timeout = -1,
            Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(apiUserName, apiPassword)
        };
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST)
        {
            RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
        };
        request.AddJsonBody(json);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        IRestResponse response = client.Post(request);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _log.LogError("Error while updating the ID: {0}, Value: {1} ---- Error: {2}", Id, value, ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

I tried with Parallel.Foreach with max 5 parallelism and noticed that i missed some of post methods or updated with wrong value.

Thanks

Comment: `foreach (var item in myList)` is written in some controller action method?

Comment: Have you asked the vendor? They might have some API function for that.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - Yes. my question more of how can I improve the performance in process of 5000 items.

Comment: @Chetan no I have written a console .net core application

Comment: You can start by reusing your RestClient, but I dont think this will give you night and day improvements.

Comment: Speak to the people that host the API, see if they can help with it. If it was my API I'd rather put a bit of work in to let you submit an array than have you batter the daylights out of my server with requests that were mostly headers

Comment: @dotnetdev you might also want to investigate into [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit), singleton object, await-async task. There is a nice disccustion to look at [parallel.foreach and httpclient - strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221977/parallel-foreach-and-httpclient-strange-behaviour)